# Unable to deploy Ruby App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm a noob to this stuff. I just deployed a different app prior to this one so I don't know if that could be the reason. Anyway, I did the standard Heroku steps to deploy but I am getting the following error:

```
    remote:        /tmp/build_70ac51f84d237880d076a5b324fee21c/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to glacial-island-90844.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/glacial-island-90844.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/glacial-island-90844.git'
```

Gemfile:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.5'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Heroku Logs:

```
    2018-06-16T11:26:38.801026+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:26:38.801026+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:26:38.953219+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:26:38.953219+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:28:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:28:49.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
2018-06-16T11:33:13.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user sbeezynen@gmail.com
2018-06-16T11:33:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build failed -- check your build logs
```

Any idea what could be causing this? I can see the heroku app from the Heroku Dashboard. I already did the 'git add -A' 'git commit' and 'git push' too.

Comment: Are you able to precompile assets locally?

Comment: Yes. If i run my rails server. It's fine.

Comment: @j_nguyen run `rake assets:precompile`, you don't normally have to run this for the dev server however it is run when you deploy, so you want to make sure it works locally

Comment: also try production version in localhost `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Answer (score 0):

There may be some CSS or JS which were enable to compile by precompiler of Heroku(Ruby on Rails). So first try to compile the files locally with enabling production mode and see if it is compiling or not if not then look for the errors it throwing. If not then it must be some configuration issue on heroku.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your css file or code on given
[link](http://www.css-validator.org/)

If any error in code then it's show or highlight on line number.